# Coffeescript not converting properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript

I am making an app in ruby on rails and this is one of my coffeescript files
I believe that my code is indented properly but I am still getting an error.
I marked the line that is giving me error with comment below.
Please help!

```
jQuery ->


    today_date = new Date()
    month = today_date.getMonth()
    day = today_date.getDay()


    pkpstyle= [
        featureType: "landscape.natural"
        elementType: "geometry"
        stylers: [
            lightness: -29
        ,
            hue: "#ffee00"
        ,
            saturation: 54
         ]
    ,
        featureType: "poi.park"
        stylers: [
            lightness: -35
        ,
            hue: "#005eff"
         ]
    ,
        featureType: "road.arterial"
    ,
        featureType: "road.arterial"
        stylers: [ lightness: 45 ]
     ]


    tempDay = 4
    //I get an error here saying Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    today_latlng = getLatlng(stops[tempDay])

    markericon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/assets/cycling.png")
    myOptions =
        center: today_latlng
        zoom: 12
        minZoom: 4
        styles: pkpstyle
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions)
    for i of stops
        latlng = getLatlng(stops[i].latlng)
        marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            map: map
            icon: markericon
            position: latlng
        )

    getLatlng = (loc) ->
        loc_split = loc.split(", ")
        lat = loc_split[0]
        lng = loc_split[1]
        new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
```

Comment: getLatLong evaluates to undefined there. What's the issue? (Does Coffeescript allow forward-declaration like that? FunctionStatements *but not* "var f = func" statements in JavaScript allow forward declaration. What does the JS end up as? I imagine as a `var`... and hence the `undefined`.)

Comment: Did you convert this code from Javascript to CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This CoffeeScript:

```
today_latlng = getLatlng(stops[tempDay])
getLatlng = (loc) ->
    loc_split = loc.split(", ")
    lat = loc_split[0]
    lng = loc_split[1]
    new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
```

Is, more or less, the same as this JavaScript:

```
var today_latlng, getLatLng;
today_latlng = getLatLng(stops[tempDay])
getLatLng = function(loc) { ... };
```

So you do have a `getLatLng` variable when you `getLatLng(stops[tempDay])` but you're not assigning it a value until *after* you try to call it as a function. You need to *define* `getLatLng` as a function before you treat it as one:

```
getLatlng = (loc) ->
    loc_split = loc.split(", ")
    lat = loc_split[0]
    lng = loc_split[1]
    new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
#...
today_latlng = getLatlng(stops[tempDay])
```

Also, if `stops` is an array then you shouldn't use an `of` loop, you should use an [`in` loop](http://coffeescript.org/#loops):

```
for p in stops
    latlng = getLatlng(p.latlng)
    #...
```

An `of` loop is the same as a `for ... in` JavaScript loop and that can do funny things with an array, an `in` loop ends up as a `for(;;)` loop in the JavaScript and that's well behaved with arrays. I don't know what `stops` is though so this might not apply, I'm just guessing based on how it is being used and the `i` index variable.